# Can you split an AC power cord into a 'y' to feed two AC loads?

Tags: ac, wiring

I usually work with low voltage DC stuff, like little Arduino circuits and things. I've had no problem powering multiple things from a single power source that need roughly the same voltage (or using buck converters to step things down, or whatever).

However, I recently had a need to have two AC loads plugged into a single outlet. The positioning of the thing sort of necessitated a 'y' shaped power cable, something like this:

[image: 1 in 2 out AC power cord splitter]

I tried to take a couple of extension cords and splice them together like this, but failed in a way that involved blowing a breaker and a lot of smoke. Obviously I was doing something wrong.

I am curious if cords like this are simply just heftier wire and maybe a different solder than I'm used to... or if there's something else going on inside that "splice block" you see there in the middle. **Can you just split an AC cord into a 'y' like this** or is there something else going on?

I've tried searching for other questions and Googling for the answer, but I don't think I even know the right terms to search for. I come up with a lot of discussion about doing this for DC power, but nothing about AC.

> Note: terminology corrected to "AC loads" that I'm connecting to the cable rather than "AC power sources" - however, even though that's not the right term, not knowing that and being able to search under the wrong term is helpful so other beginners like me might find the answer *and* learn the right term - as noted, I didn't even know what to Google - so... this little "AC power source" explanation block is here for searchability.

Comment: The cut-up extension cords should have had three wires inside: Line (black), Neutral (white) and Ground (green). You just need to connect all of the same-color wires together -- one connection for all of the blacks, another for all of the whites, and a third for all of the greens. What did you actually do?

Comment: You write _"have two AC power sources plugged into a single outlet."_ but do you actually mean AC _loads_?

Comment: You cannot bridge two different AC sources into one outlet and combining the same sources offers no real advantage if limited by the same breaker.

Comment: And two sources, like two generators may not work well together...

Comment: @mbedded do you mean a grid tied inverter?

Comment: @SolarMike Yeah.  I'm curious, but I think it's off-topic here.  Unless that's what he actually meant...

Comment: @mbedded used Trace inverters that control the battery bank, solar panels and can fire up an ice generator to cope with high loads ...

Comment: @DaveTweed I _thought_ I had connected them up color-to-color correctly but potentially did not, or something potentially shorted; that's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: @winny uh.... yeeesss? Think, like, outlet => y cable => lamp plugged into one part of the y cable and radio plugged into another. But it was two AC power adapters/DC converters plugged in, not a lamp and a radio.

Comment: Then please edit your question accordingly. An AC/DC adapter is _not_ an AC source.

Comment: ... and the question title.

Comment: if it made smoke that was probably a bad splice (high resistance)
that would heat up and burn the insulation leading to a short circuit and a breaker tripping. or it could have just been that the insulation wass of poor quality.

Comment: why don't you buy a power bar https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5cRZ.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they exist, however i dont recommend you do them yourself as mistakes are deadly. Just purchase a proper Y wire online.

Your mistake was probably shorting the live and neutral wires together. This should be avoided at all costs. The commercial wires dont have anything special in them, just doing the wiring the correct way arround and with proper soldering.

Comment: I think you're right, I probably had a short somewhere. I didn't know these existed until after I'd made the mistake so I was curious if it was something I did wrong (yes) or if there is some sort of "special sauce" making this work (no). Now I know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

no there's nothing special about this type of adapter. As long as all Earths, all Neutrals and all Lives wires are connected only to each other, and not mixed up in any way, then it should be fine. You may have crossed over one to the other and this may have caused your problem in the first place, but then you'd be the only one knowing if this was the case or not. Why bother making one when they do exist and are relatively cheap ...

Comment: I didn't know such a thing existed at the time. Then I found that they did and did get one... but wondered why my previous effort failed, like if it was something I did wrong. And... sounds like it was something I did wrong. :)